# When I am running project using spring boot. It is working fine. But When I am deploying it in tomcat. I am getting Below Written Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.GaugeService com.snapdeal.cpp.metrics.SDBootMetricPublisher.gaugeService; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.GaugeService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

NOTE: In case of Spring boot, I am using this annotation on class level.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/application-context*.xml")
@ComponentScan({"com.cpp.*"})
public class CPPApplication{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(CPPApplication.class);
        application.setShowBanner(false);
        application.run(args);
}
```

When I am running my application using above main method. It is working fine.

But When I am removing this code and trying to run this application using web.xml with same application context. It is giving error. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in Spring Boot, Spring has no problem finding your CPPApplication annotations, but when deployed as a war you need to have these annotations on a class that extends SpringBootServletInitializer.

This is described in detail here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html